# SQL query to find unique values

Tags: sql, arcgis

I need to write a query that truncates based on a selection and outputs another table. The selection criteria is as follows: for each common ID loop through the AGREE column to find a Y, if  no Y then output 0, if a single Y then output that year, if multiple Y then output the most current year.

Input table:

```
ID  AGREE   YEAR
1   N   2003

2   Y   2005
2   N   2015

3   N   2005    
3   N   2007
3   Y   2011
3   Y   1999

4   N   2005
4   N   2010
```

Output table:

```
ID  AGREE   YEAR

1   N   0
2   Y   2005
3   Y   2011
4   N   0
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution:

```
Select id, max(agree), max(case when agree = 'Y' then year else 0 end)
from [input table]
group by id
```

It rests on grouping by the id field and using max statements to return a "Y" if it is present for the group, and then return the largest number for year when agree is "Y". Note that you say "most recent" - if this table contains years in the future it would not return the most recent but instead the furthest into the future.

Note: There is an alternate way of doing this that is often faster that involves using sub-queries. If you run into performance issues it would be worth pursuing.

Comment: thanks TPhe. However, i forgot to add there are other columns in the table. How would I tweak your query so that other column values are added based on the above selection. The other columns don't need to be queried.

Comment: It depends a bit on the circumstances, but very simply you could just add the field to both the Select clause and also the group by clause. Any field that is in the select clause but is not used in an aggregate function, such as max(), must be in the group by clause.